# React Route content triggers twice

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Why does this alert trigger twice?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <Route path="" render={props => {
            fetch('some_path').then(response => response.json)
                .then(data => {
                    alert("i show up twice!");
                    return <p>something</p>
                });
    </Router>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I want to parse querystring and then pass data accordingly and i noticed that the code is ran twice. I exemplified with a simple alert.

EDIT: I dug a little deeper and apparently the issue is not because i don't return anything but rather because i fetch something. I updated the example.

Comment: I think `giving` it a `path="/"` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @Massimiliano hinted around a response i post this separate answer because i don't feel that one is complete.

In the code snippet i provided in the original question, the issue was that i was trying to fetch data before rendering the component (i was thinking of passing the fetched data as params to the component).

The correct way to do it is to render the component and then use `componentDidMount()` from react component's lifecycle. There i parsed the querystring, fetched the data and updated the state (using `this.setState()`).

As the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) say, calling `componentDidMount()` will trigger a re-render but it happens before the page gets rendered by the browser in the first place. So the user won't see it as a double render even though behind the scenes, it is.

I did not manage to find out exactly why i can't fetch data in the `<Route>` but the flow i described above is the correct approach to what i needed.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are not returning anything to the Route component to render.
Try this:

```
   ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Route
      path=""
      render={props => {
        fetch("some_path")
          .then(response => response.json)
          .then(data => {
            alert("i show up twice!");
            return <p>something</p>;
          });
        return <p>something</p>;
      }}
    />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was actually the issue, but could you tell me why does it happen this way? Is it like a second attempt or something more obscure happening behind `react-router-dom` ?

Comment: i think this is something related to the implementation of react-router-dom but i don't have a deep knowledge of it, so i can't really tell you why it happens.

Comment: I updated the question. I was mistaken at first. I need to fetch something and then return. But even so, i get that alert twice.

Comment: that's still the issue. When you are fetching you are not returning anything to the Route Component on the first render because the fetch await the promise (.then) to return something. If you look at the console you should see a warning related to Route telling you: Nothing was returned from render.

Comment: I edited the answer to show you how to make it work but probably for your goal you need to create a component that fetches the data you want in the ComponentDidMount and render that component in the Route component.

Comment: Well if you change your example in order to have different phrases in the `<p>` tags, you will notice that the return inside the fetch will never render in the browser. I will try with a wrapper class with `ComponentDidMount` but honestly i was hoping i could do it all in one go, without another component that just distributes content.

Comment: yeah it doesn't render anything because i already returned the <p> outside of the fetch and since i'm not using the react state it is not aware of the modification. However if you use the additional component with the state you will still have 2 renders: one when you first render the component and one when you update the state after you fetch the data. But this way it will be a normal behavior and not one caused by not returning anything to the Route. Hope it helps :)